# I cannot open my C menu or use weapons - Error in Console

Tags: garrys-mod

I am getting this error on my Sandbox server. I completely reinstalled my server but I still get this error. I think it may be an addon.

```
[ERROR] gamemodes/sandbox/gamemode/cl_init.lua:86: attempt to call field 'PostRenderVGUI' (a nil value)
  1. old_hook_call - gamemodes/sandbox/gamemode/cl_init.lua:86
   2. unknown - lua/includes/modules/momo/compat.lua:23
```

Answer (score 0):

Try verifying the integrity of the game cache on steam. just right click the game on the steam library menu>then press properties>the go to local files>then click verify the integrity of game cache. that will probably work.

Comment: I don't think it will work on a server. That is client side, it is server side.

Comment: oh I thought it was the whole game

Comment: @CamouflagedCow Both the client and server can be validated, although if you're using steamcmd for the server, the directions are a bit different.